# Crop image in Android using perfect aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, screen, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio

I have been working on an android application. There is feature in my application which requires an image with exact dimensions of device screen, for which i am using this code,

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", width);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", height);
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

but the problem with this code is that since aspect ratio has been set to zero, in some devices like samsung, the crop window is in square size and cannot be adjusted. So how could i set the aspect ratio in aspectX as well as aspectY field so that there is no problem in image cropping,

I have also written a java progrem to calculate aspect ratio but it doesnt seem to work nice with all resolutions.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class AspectRatio
{   public static void main(String args[])
    {   BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int width=0,height=0;
        try
        {   System.out.print("Enter the width of the screen:");
            width=Integer.parseInt(buff.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter the height of the screen:");
            height=Integer.parseInt(buff.readLine());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int factor=0;
        for(int i=2;i<new AspectRatio().minimum(width,height)/2;i++)
        {   if(width%i==0&&height%1==0)
            {   factor=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The aspect ratio is:"+width/factor+":"+height/factor);
    }

    public int minimum(int a,int b)
    {   return (a<b?a:b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the Width and Height from the System using the next Class : 
[DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

check the link it will also give the example how to use this class..

Comment: And what about aspect ratio..?

Comment: i am already using this code to get width and height and it is working only with few devices

Comment: first if you want to keep an Image AspectRatio just use AspectRatioImageView assuming your going to display this image inside ImageViiew.. and for a big soultion use something that the system gives you like the DisplayMetric here is the link for the AspectRatioImageView : https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/2856179

Answer (score 0):

this is my helper class to reduce any image with perfect ratio and it works with image taken from camera and img on the device:

```
 public class ImageUtils {
    private static final String TAG = "ImageUtils";
    private static final float maxHeight = 1280.0f;
    private static final float maxWidth = 1280.0f;

    public static byte[] compressImage(String imagePath) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;


        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
        float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        options.inSampleSize = ImageUtils.calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
    public static boolean compressImage(Bitmap image, FileOutputStream fos){
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        int actualHeight = image.getHeight();
        int actualWidth = image.getWidth();
        float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "ActualHeight " + actualHeight);
        Log.d(TAG, "ActualHidht " + actualWidth);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = ImageUtils.calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
//            int bytes = byteSizeOf(image);
//            //or we can calculate bytes this way. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
//            //int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4;
//            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
//            image.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer
//            byte[] array = buffer.array(); //Get the underlying array containing the data.
//            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length, options);

            ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
            byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata.length);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//        ExifInterface exif;
//        try {
////            exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
////            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
////            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
////            if (orientation == 6) {
////                matrix.postRotate(90);
////            } else if (orientation == 3) {
////                matrix.postRotate(180);
////            } else if (orientation == 8) {
////                matrix.postRotate(270);
////            }
//
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), null, true);
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fos);
        return true;
    }
    public static void compressImage(String imagePath, FileOutputStream fos) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
        float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        options.inSampleSize = ImageUtils.calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fos);
    }
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
    static protected int byteSizeOf(Bitmap data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
            return data.getRowBytes() * data.getHeight();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return data.getByteCount();
        } else {
            return data.getAllocationByteCount();
        }
    }
}


 /**
 * reduces the size of the image
 * @param image
 * @param maxSize
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}

private void setVideoViewRatio(VideoView vv, int maxSize, int cWidth, int cHeight){
    int width = cWidth;
    int height = cHeight;
    float ratio = (float)cWidth / (float) height;
    if (ratio > 0) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / ratio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * ratio);
    }
    vv.setMinimumWidth(width);
    vv.setMinimumHeight(height);
}
```